# Different text new unique button state

Tags: user-interface, rust

I am running into this error code `cannot borrow bars.upload as mutable more than once at a time bars.upload was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the looprustcE0499`
Here is the code

```rust
let scrollable_row = Row::with_children(
    self.bars
        .iter_mut()
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(i, bars)| {
            let mut scrollable =
                Scrollable::new(&mut bars.scrollable)
                    .padding(10)
                    .spacing(10)
                    .width(Length::Fill)
                    .height(Length::Fill)
                    .on_scroll(move |offset| {
                        Message::Scrolled(i, offset)
                    })
                    .style(self.theme)
                    .push(Text::new(bars.title))
                    .push(Text::new(bars.desc));

            for j in 0..bars.content.len() {
                scrollable = scrollable
                    .push(
                    iced::Button::new(
                        &mut bars.upload,
                        Text::new(bars.content[j].clone()))
                    );
            }
```

Is there a way to link them together, I would like the button states to be different but in a for loop. Is there a way around this like maybe creating a new button state for each or all togther avoiding button states. What i am trying to do is create mutiple buttons without knowing how many buttons i need. I do not mind using a pick list or a radio button if it is possible. Btw all i need is the name that is clicked (bars.upload) which i pass into the message state TLDR; make mutiple unique buttons in for loop

Comment: Each button can own one single `State`. You need somewhere to put the `State` though, that will outlive the button.

Comment: ("Own" is the wrong term there, but what I mean is you can't share a `State` between buttons.)

Comment: @cdhowie I feel like this is impossible on any GUI especially in low-level languages. I think im going to move in a different direction unless someone has a better idea

Comment: It's not impossible -- you just need somewhere to put the `State` values.

Comment: @GrandmaKisses why do you think this is impossible? It's just how Rust works, it's not always intuitive (especially at the beginning), but there is nothing impossible.

Comment: @BlackBeans Well with my current logic ( obv nothing is impossible :) ) I think it is just a limitation in most GUI libraries but tbh I found a way around it and clearly not currently good enough in rust and GUIs to make a git commit but maybe in the future i can make GUIs even better!

Comment: I'm not seeing this "limitation." You make a `State`, put it somewhere, and give a reference to `Button::new()`. You seem a bit confused about what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look https://github.com/iced-rs/iced/blob/master/examples/todos/src/main.rs which implements a saved state in the form of json and makes use of dynamic size buttons. This would be too long for this stackoverflow answer but it is possible and there are no limitations